# OpenAL / Webassembly: how to consume the captured audio data

Tags: c, go, socket.io, webassembly, openal

I am working on a prototype in which I send the sound data from OpenAL (front end using webassembly) to a backend through `socket.io` and then write the data to a file. It works fine, except that after I write all the raw data to a file(e.g test.raw), and try to convert it to wav format, I get noise only. I tried both `ffmpeg` and `sox` without any luck:

- sox -r 44100 -e signed-integer -b 16 -c 1 test.raw out_sox.wav
- ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -c:a pcm_s16le -i test.raw out.wav -y

Here is the program used for sound capture:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 64


int cnt=0;

void mycallback(void *arg)
{
    ALCint nframes;
    ALCdevice *dev = (ALCdevice*)arg;

    alcGetIntegerv(dev, ALC_CAPTURE_SAMPLES, 1, &nframes);

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    if(nframes>0)
    {
        alcCaptureSamples(dev, buffer, nframes);

        cnt++;

        char *command = (char *)malloc(2000);

        command = strcpy(command, "socket.emit('record', [");
      
         for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {

            char currentValue[30];
            sprintf(currentValue, "%d", buffer[i]);

            command = strcat(command, currentValue);

            if (i != sizeof(buffer) - 1) {
                command = strcat(command, ", ");
            }
        }

        command = strcat(command, "])");

        emscripten_run_script(command);

        free(command); 
    }

    if (cnt > 1000) {
        emscripten_cancel_main_loop();
        fprintf(stdout, " -#################### Done! \n");
        emscripten_run_script("socket.close()");
    }
}

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int record() {
    
    ALCdevice *dev = NULL;

    emscripten_run_script("console.log('recording ')");

    dev = alcCaptureOpenDevice(alcGetString(NULL, ALC_CAPTURE_DEVICE_SPECIFIER), 44100, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, BUFFER_SIZE);
    ALCcontext *context = alcCreateContext(dev, NULL);

    alcCaptureStart(dev);

    emscripten_set_main_loop_arg(mycallback, dev, -1, 1);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    emscripten_run_script("console.log('start recording ====== ')");
    record();
}
```

and here is a snippet from the backend:

```
//imports, etc..

server, err := socketio.NewServer(nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    f, err := os.OpenFile("test.raw", os.O_CREATE, 0600)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    server.OnEvent("/", "record", func(s socketio.Conn, data []rune) string {

        fmt.Printf(" recording test, received %d \n", len(data))

        err = binary.Write(f, binary.BigEndian, []byte(string(data)))

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }

        return "ok"
    })


//run server,...etc
```

I am wondering if I am missing on some settings, or simply doing things wrong. I am using `AL_FORMAT_MONO16` for the data format. I am also sending the data as int array and then converting to byte before writing it to the file, any help would appreciated.

Comment: Hi Zakaria, did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I moved on to using WebRTC from JavaScript directly